# Can't modify system file in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have a NAS Lenovo Iomega Store IX2-200 Cloud Edition running Debian 7 and a Twonky Media Server and I'm having 2 problems.

1) I need to modify the twonky configuration file /usr/local/twonky/twonkyvision-mediaserver.ini but the file is read-only. I'm logged as root and can't modify or even do chown root to this file. The system returns the error "Read-only file system".

```
root@ix2:/# chown root /usr/local/twonky/twonkyvision-mediaserver.ini
chown: changing ownership of `/usr/local/twonky/twonkyvision-mediaserver.ini': Read-only file system
```

2) Aptitude and apt-get doesn't work and the following errors are returned:

```
root@ix2:/usr/local/twonky# aptitude update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Thats wierd because I'm root and the systems is asking if i'm root.

The /var/lib/dpkg/ doesn't exist and I can't make it and use aptitude or apt-get.

When I try aptitude it says:
`root@ix2:/# aptitude update E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device) E: Can't mmap an empty file E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (9: Bad file descriptor) E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened. E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory) E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.`

my disk is almost empty

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like the filesystem is mounted read-only, either due to design or some error ... what is in /etc/fstab and what does the mount command give for output?

Comment: Your disk is full.

Comment: @ivanivan
`# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount pt>     <type>   <options>         <dump> <pass>
/dev/root       /              ext2     rw,noauto         0      1
proc            /proc          proc     defaults          0      0
none            /proc/bus/usb   usbfs   defaults        0       0
none            /proc/fs/nfsd   nfsd    defaults        0       0
none            /sys            sysfs   defaults          0      0
devpts          /dev/pts       devpts   defaults,gid=5,mode=620   0      0

/mnt/system/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0`

Comment: and the mount command returned
`root@ix2:/# mount
/dev/root.old on /initrd type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue)
none on / type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=51200k,nr_inodes=30949)
/dev/md0_vg/BFDlv on /boot type ext2 (rw,noatime,sync,errors=continue)
/dev/loop0 on /mnt/apps type ext2 (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop1 on /mnt/etc type ext2 (rw,noatime,sync)
none on /etc type unionfs (rw,noatime,sync,dirs=/mnt/etc=rw:/mnt/apps/etc=ro)
/dev/loop2 on /oem type squashfs (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)`

Comment: continued:
`none on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=24776k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=49540k)
/dev/mapper/md0_vg-vol1 on /mnt/system type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=1,data=ordered)`

Comment: @ivanivan continued:
`/dev/mapper/21c99916_vg-lv1d56b456 on /mnt/pools/A/A0 type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=0,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/21c99916_vg-lv1d56b456 on /nfs/Lorenco type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=0,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/21c99916_vg-lv1d56b456 on /nfs/Laura type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=0,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/21c99916_vg-lv1d56b456 on /nfs/Cristina type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=0,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/21c99916_vg-lv1d56b456 on /nfs/Lara type ext4 (rw,noatime,barrier=0,data=ordered)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)`

Answer (score 1):

A read only filesystem is one filesystem that has been mounted readonly or that due to a improper shutdown needs repair.  Linux makes this automatically for filesystems when it finds some inconsistency that must be repaired manually by the administrator (possible filesystem data corruption).  Run `fsck(1)` on that filesystem to see if some repair has to be done.  If a filesystem is mounted read-only, even root user is unable to modify files on it.

Comment: Hi!
Run `root@ix2:/# fsck(1)
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token '1'`

and
`root@ix2:/# fsck
fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/root
Possibly non-existent device?`

Answer (score 0):

#### Hacking a Debian based NAS

A Iomega prepare a limited debian installation, stored in *raw disk images*, located on `/boot` (hit `losetup -a` too see loop binds). you could either:

1. modify images stored in `/boot`, it's a strong work and if you do some error, you'r nas will become unuseable.
2. Don't touch anything in `/boot` but you could not use `apt`, from there. You have to copy unpacked .deb files in a directory located under `/mnt/pool` and create symlinks.

The way I chooses is the less destructive one.

1. Store all your stuff under hard disk, somewhere under `/mnt/pool/`
2. Create symlinks to bind your stuff to `/usr/local/`
3. If you really need to acces /, you have to remount them with `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: nope, do a full filesystem check first.  Remounting rw a filesystem that has been switched read-only by the kernel can only give you more trouble or continue until it has no repair.

Comment: Hi!
`root@ix2:/# fsck -A
fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/root
Possibly non-existent device?`

Comment: @LorençoSantos Answer edited. As `/` is a `unionfs`, you probably just need to empty the `rw` partition mounted on `/` by *unionfs*